# How x509chain works in C#? I have a problem

Tags: x509certificate2

I´m developing a certificate validation module, and I´m using `X509Chain` for to verify certificates chain. Basically my code is:

```
X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();
ch.Build(cert);
```

In Debug mode work perfectly, but when I compile as DLL and I execute I get:

> "The chain context handle is invalid"

Any help will be Appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's the callstack where you get that error?  The only places that should produce that error are if you called `Build` with a `null` certificate or an already-disposed certificate; or you used `new X509Chain(IntPtr.Zero)` instead of `new X509Chain()`.

Comment: Thanks bartonjs, Error is produced in Build method. The certificate is correct, is vaiid and the constructor is X509Chain() not IntPtr.Zero

Comment: Does adding `GC.KeepAlive(cert)` after the call to `ch.Build(cert)` make the problem go away?

Comment: The problem is in the ch.Build(cert) sentence, right there is where program get crash, by that never will excute GC.keepAlive(cert). My surprise is that the program excute without problem in debug mode.

Comment: GC.KeepAlive isn’t a real method, it stops a “GC hole” where an object gets finalized after the last reference but while it’s still needed. It fixes weird problems like the one you are describing (which only happen in Release builds)

Comment: Bartonjs, thanks for your suggestion, but no I got the same, The message say "context", what is the different on context between debug mode and release mode ? because in debug mode work well

Comment: “Context” is just what Windows calls the chain and cert objects. The only real difference between debug and release that should matter here is that release can call objects dead earlier, which might trigger finalizers. If you have any finalizers which would call Dispose or Reset on the cert, you might need to a) not do that (finalizers should not touch managed objects) and b) might need to better “root” your objects. The only way you’d get that exception is if the cert was invalid (Reset or Dispose was called, it’s null, or it was created by the default constructor).

Comment: Bartonjs, thanks for your time, what do you mean with "root" ?

Comment: Bartonjs, I apologize, but your suggestions opened my head. I was always going through the error and I didn't see it. I have an environment to test my logic with debug and sometimes they differ a bit from the true release module. Well, in release mode I was assigning the certificate after the validation call, that is, I was verifying a null certificate, incredible but real ! Thanks again for your time and thanks for helping me.